# SVN project folder tree structure vs production folder tree structure

Tags: svn, project-management, directory

While developing a PHP+JS web application we always try to separate big blocks of code into small modules/components, in order to make these last ones as much reusable as possible in other applications.

Let's say we now have:

1. the `EcommerceApp` (an ecommerce main application)
2. a `Server-file-mgr` component (a component to view/manage file on server)
3. a `Mylib` (a library of useful functions)
4. a `MailistApp` (another main application to handle mail lists)

...

- `EcommerceApp` needs both `Server-file-mgr` component and `Mylib` to work
- `Server-file-mgr` needs `Mylib` to work
- `MaillistApp` needs both `Server-file-mgr` component and `Mylib` to work too.

My idea is to simply structure the SVN project folder tree putting everything at the same level:

```
trunk/EcommerceApp
trunk/Server-file-mgr
trunk/Mylib
trunk/MaillistApp
```

But in real life to make these apps to work the folder tree structure must be the following:

```
EcommerceApp
 |_ Mylib
 |_ Server-file-mgr

MaillistApp
 |_ Mylib
 |_ Server-file-mgr
```

I mean `Mylib` and `Server-file-mgr` needs to be inside the `EcommerceApp/MaillistApp` folder.

**How would you then structure the SVN folder, as I did or in a different/better/smarter way???**

EDIT: somoene in the answers below suggested to structure SVN as real life folders, but I would then have on SVN two copies of the same folder, I mean I would have a trunk/EcommerceApp/Mylib and another copy under trunk/MaillistApp/Mylib, how would I keep them synchronized???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest the second one (as for real live). But i would suggest to create separate "Modules" for MyLib and Server-file-mgr (with their own trunk/tags/branches) if they are used anywhere else than in that product and use svn:externals to link them together. You can handle them as separate libraries.

EDIT:

```
trunk/
  EcommerceApp
   |_ Mylib
   |_ Server-file-mgr

  MaillistApp
   |_ Mylib
   |_ Server-file-mgr
```

You could do the following with svn:externals: You have to put them into Project/trunk folder.

```
Project/
   |_ trunk/
        |_ EcommerceApp (link to MyLib->tags/RELEASE-1.0)
        |_ MaillistApp (link to Server-file-mgr->tags/RELEASE-1.0)
   |_ tags
   |_ branches

MyLib/
   |_ trunk
   |_ tags
       |_ RELEASE-1.0
   |_ branches

Server-file-mgr/
   |_ trunk
   |_ tags
       |_ RELEASE-1.0
   |_ branches
```

Everytime you are creating a new release of MyLib or Server-file-mgr you can simply change the svn:externals in Project/trunk. So with this you have a separate development for your components.

Comment: Thanks, I know it's better to have each one it's own trunk, but I did not want to reduce the answer comprehinsion. If I use the 2nd one as you suggest i would have on SVN two copies of the same folder, I mean I would have a trunk/EcommerceApp/Mylib and another copy under trunk/MaillistApp/Mylib, how would I keep them synchronized???

Comment: I talked about svn:externals this is no copy!

Comment: thanks `svn:externals` is exactly what I was looking for. To whom it may concern at this link http://e-mats.org/2008/05/adding-an-external-svn-resource-with-tortoise/ they provide a nice explanation on how to use `svn:externals` with TortoiseSVN

Answer (score 0):

You could use symbolic links (if you're on linux), if the only requirement is to be able to access them locally from `EcommerceApp` and `MaillistApp` directories. SVN is able to store symbolic links correctly.

```
trunk/EcommerceApp
 |-  Mylib -> ../Mylib
 |-  Server-file-mgr -> ../Server-file-mgr
trunk/Server-file-mgr
trunk/Mylib
trunk/MaillistApp
 |-  Mylib -> ../Mylib
 |-  Server-file-mgr -> ../Server-file-mgr
```

Comment: I'm not on Unix, and I use Tortoise SVn with no symbolyc link.